# Inserting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless InsertCommand is specified

Tags: asp.net

I am having a problem ,

The problem is i have created asp.net website . I am using Details view to insert records .

I am using access data source to connect the database file . i am getting an error the error is

### Server Error in '/WebSite3' Application.

Inserting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless InsertCommand is specified. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Inserting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless InsertCommand is specified.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NotSupportedException: Inserting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless InsertCommand is specified.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) +1967663
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +89
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleInsert(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation) +379
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +574
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +112
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +169
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225

Please help me,

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the insert command and the insert parameters for `SqlDataSource1`.

This article will walk you through how to do inserts using the SqlDataSource control:

[Inserting with a SqlDataSource control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insert.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a walkthrough of what you are trying to do:

[Walkthrough: Editing and Inserting Data in Web Pages with the DetailsView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdba1d59%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)